# Number formatting in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, number-formatting

so I got this really small problem.

I am redoing old crystal reports into new ssrs reports and encountered this in formula expert

```
ToText ({DB.Table},1)
```

And I've been trying to find out what this little "1" does. Is it saying "show only one decimal" or something completely different??

Never done anything in crystal reports except doing similar reports in ssrs, so i apologize for my ignorance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the 2nd (optional) argument controls number of decimals.
The 3rd (optional) argument controls thousand separator.
You can get very useful help within the Crystal formula editor by placing your cursor inside the function name and hitting F1.